# How to filter results by a linked property in Api-Platform?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4, api-platform.com

I have a `User` Entity and a `Organisation` entity, there is a relation `ManyToOne` between `Booking` and `User`:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="bookings")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $user;
```

The `User` entity has a property called country. I would like to setup the bookings to only display the records made by users with the same country as the logged user. This is what I tried

```
collectionOperations={
*          "get"={
*              "access_control"="object.getUser().getOrganisation() == user.organisation"
*              "normalization_context"={
*                  "groups"={"read"}
*              }
*          },
```

of course it does not work.

I know I can filter passing parameters in the query string but I need these results to be filtered on API side not by the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the [Security page of the docs](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/security/#filtering-collection-according-to-the-current-user-permissions) says:

> Filtering collections according to the role or permissions of the current user must be done directly at the data provider level. For instance, when using the built-in adapters for Doctrine ORM, MongoDB and ElasticSearch, removing entries from a collection should be done using extensions.

Looking at [extensions](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/extensions/), you would need to do something like:

```
final class BookingOwnerExtension implements QueryCollectionExtensionInterface
{
    private $security;

    public function __construct(Security $security)
    {
        $this->security = $security;
    }

public function applyToCollection(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, QueryNameGeneratorInterface $queryNameGenerator, string $resourceClass, string $operationName = null)
    {
        if (Booking::class !== $resourceClass || $this->security->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN') || null === $user = $this->security->getUser()) {
            return;
        }

        $organization = $user->getOrganization()

        $rootAlias = $queryBuilder->getRootAliases()[0];
        $queryBuilder
            ->leftJoin(sprintf('%s.user', $rootAlias), 'u')
            ->andWhere('user.organization = :organization')
            ->setParameter('organization', $organization);
    }
}
```

(The exact query would depend on what you intend to do, since I'm not familiar with your application I can only point you in the right direction. But that's just adding a the appropriate conditions to the query using the query builder).

This is most likely enough, although if you are not using auto-configuration you would have to register the custom extension with the appropriate tags:

```
# api/config/services.yaml
services:
    # ...

    'App\Doctrine\BookingOwnerExtension':
        tags:
            - { name: api_platform.doctrine.orm.query_extension.collection }
```

Comment: thanks @yivi, now I understand the process. 

If I filter by '%s.user = :user', it works, it only returns me the record inserted by that user. 

If I try to filter by '%s.user.organization = :organization' it gets me an error "Class App\\Entity\\Booking has no field or association named user.organisation". 

Any idea why?

Comment: Yeah, that's mostly a doctrine/query builder issue, kinda out of scope for this question. My code above is almost pseudo-code, since I have no idea how your database schema works (and "how to write a doctrine query" is not the question here). But basically you would probably need to add a left join between bookings and user, and apply the where in that level. I'll add some generic code, but the final design you'll have to finish yourself. This just tells you how to accomplish this filtering in Api-Platform, the real question here.

Comment: it works as expected. just changed the alias in andWhere from user. to u. Many thanks for your help.